# Update firebase reference name

Tags: firebase

I am trying to update the name of a firebase reference.

ie.

I have in firebase:

```
user@example.com => {first: John, last: Doe}
```

and i want to rename 'user@example.com' to '1'.

I cannot seem to find a proper way to do this in the Firebase docs apart from copying the contents of 'user@example.com' into a new reference called '1' and then deleting the old reference. Is this correct?

- I am working in Ruby with the Bigbertha gem.
- I am aware of the issues
  with periods when using emails as reference names in firebase, and am
  replacing those with ','.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as far as I have learned, this is true. You can only copy the data and delete the reference then.

Of course, you might also consider changing your data structure so that you only store the email as a value somewhere, not as an identifier.